# Procmail: Forwarding email dynamically

Tags: php, email, forward, procmail

I want to use procmail to forward all incoming email to an email address. Normally I would just do this:

```
:0
! email@domain.com
```

BUT: In this case I don't know the receiver. Insteasd, the receiver is calculated by a PHP script based on the incoming email content.

So I need something like this:

```
:0c
| /usr/bin/php /var/www/calculatereceiver.php   <== The output of this script is the $RECEIVER address

:0
! $RECEIVER
```

Of course the above code doesn't work. My problem is: How can I manage that procmail forwards the mail to the output of thwe first script?

Best greetings,

Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Procmail: program/script output to variable (email on STDIN)

Try the following:

```
RECEIVER=`/usr/bin/php /var/www/calculatereceiver.php`

:0
! $RECEIVER
```

More secure version that may not work with all sendmail look alikes:

```
RECEIVER=`/usr/bin/php /var/www/calculatereceiver.php`

:0
! -- $RECEIVER
```

### Documentation references

`man procmailrc` :

> Any program in backquotes started by procmail will have the entire mail at its stdin

Comment: Thanks a lot but in that case, the php script won't receive the original mail as stdin, which it needs to calculate the receiver...?

Comment: The documentation (man procmailrc) states otherwise. I have appended the relevant quote to the answer.